Sort RSS feeds by date?
Looking for info on formatting RSS feeds - I found mine but is there information somewhere on formatting the feed? I would like it by date rather than by type.
https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/75001

I might be able to work around by using several individual feeds for action types if I can find them.
